# MongoDb insertOne and return get _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I tried to get _id inserted object:

```
let id;
db.collection("collection-name")
  .insertOne(document)
  .then(result => {
  id = result.insertedId;
  console.log(result.insertedId);
})
  .catch(err => {

});

console.log("id", id);
```

In console I see `insertedId` but how to get it outside `then`

after `insertOne` in console I see `id undefind`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As nodejs is non blocking so the order of execution will be like this

1. `let id;`
2. `console.log("id", id);`
   At this point id is `undefined` so `id undefined` is printed
3. At last this will be executed

---

```
db.collection("collection-name")
  .insertOne(document)
  .then(result => {
  id = result.insertedId;
  console.log(result.insertedId);
})
  .catch(err => {

});
```

but if you want to wait for the result before you can print it you can use `async/wait`

```
(async function () {
  let result = await db.collection("collection-name").insertOne(document);
  console.log("id", result.insertedId);
})();
```

Comment: Actually it prints  `Promise { <pending> }`

Answer (score 1):

inserOne is an asynchronous function. The insertOne function is sent for execution in the background while your console.log(id) is printed before it. One thing is you can do it in the .then function

```
let id;
db.collection("collection-name")
  .insertOne(document)
  .then(result => {
  id = result.insertedId;
  console.log(result.insertedId);
  // here you have the acccess
  console.log("id", id);
}).catch(err => {
    
});
```

The other solution is to wait until the promise from insertOne is resolved using async/await.

```
async function insert(){
   let id;
   let result = await db.collection("collection-name").insertOne(document);
   id = result.insertedId;
   console.log(id)
}
```

await will only work with async functions

Answer (score 0):

If your mongo collection structure has `_id` unless you have changed it. Maybe that causes the code to output `undefined`

Have you tried `id = result._id` instead?

Comment: no - console.log(result.insertedId); print me new _id its works